# Really awkward (seemingly simple) bug with python integer comparisons

Tags: python, identity, equality

I have the following piece of code which is not working the way I expect it to at all...

```
current_frame = 15 # just for showcasing purposes
g_ch = 7

if (current_frame != int(row[0])) and (int(row[1]) != g_ch):
                current_frame = int(row[0])
                print "curious================================="
                print current_frame
                print row
                print current_frame, " != ", int(row[0]), ", ", current_frame != int(row[0])
                print "========================================"
```

which prints for any specific case:

```
curious================================= 

15 

['15', '1', 'more data'] 15 != 15 , False

========================================
```

This should obviously never even enter the if statement, as the equality is showing false.  Why is this happening?

edit:  I have also tried this with != instead of 'is not', and gotten the same results.

Comment: Value equality should not be confused with identity.

Comment: Since you say this happens with `!=` as will as `is not`, please omit `current_frame = int(row[0])` and show `print repr(current_frame)` and `print repr(row[0])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Value comparisons are done with the `!=` operator, not with `is not`, which compares object identity.

Apart from that, I think it's an indentation problem.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I had done this as well, and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to use `==` and `!=`, and not `is`. `is` compares object identity, not equality.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `current_frame = int(row[0])` inside the if, which changes the value of the boolean expression.